# Finding the centerpoint and boundaries of an arbitrary closed curve (random walk)

Tags: graphics, graph, geometry, computational-geometry, numerical-methods

Suppose you have an arbitrary closed curve (endpoint returns relatively close to first point) generated through a bunch of dataset coordinates, how do you find the centerpoint and the boundaries of the resulting shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations (perhaps more) for your question.

The first one was already addressed by @AakashM, and we may depict it in the following plot:
[image]

Where the red square is the "boundary".
I'll cite @AakashM here, because I understand his remark VERY important:*"(I note that for you to have a closed curve, you need the endpoint to be not just 'close to', but coincident with the first point)"*

As for the centerpoint, you have at least two "natural ways" for calculating it with this definitions:

1. Centerpoint = Middle Point of the Red Square
2. Centerpoint = { Mean of x coordinates of your curve, Mean of y coordinates of your curve}

Both of them may serve as a center point, but the results will be different.

The other way of dealing with the problem is finding the [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your curve, as depicted below:

[image]

If you google for it, you will find algorithms for finding the Convex Hull, a nice introduction is [here](http://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/convexHull/index.html).

Again, you have two "natural ways for calculating the centerpoint:

1. Centerpoint = { Mean of x coordinates of your curve, Mean of y coordinates of your curve}
2. Centerpoint = { Mean of x coordinates of the CH points, Mean of y coordinates of the CH points}

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

(I note that for you to have a *closed* curve, you need the endpoint to be not just 'close to', but *coincident with* the first point)

If by 'centerpoint' you mean center of mass, and you are assuming uniform density, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408358/finding-the-center-of-mass-on-a-2d-bitmap) has what you want.

If by 'boundaries' you mean bounding rectangle with sides parallel to the axes, you just need the minimum and maximum x and y values on the curve.

If either of those aren't what you mean, please say...

Answer (score 0):

For the boundaries, you can refer to the answers given by @belisarius and @AakashM.

As for centerpoint, you want "center of mass".  Good 'ol Wikipedia has explanations and recipes at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid.

In general, you get a different result calculating the centroid than calculating the average of the vertices.  This difference will be pronounced if the vertices are not uniformly distributed.